# Upload a files in S3 as soon as it arrives in a folder

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

i am rephrasing my question again because got devoted for not posting clearly .
So i have a folder where i will be getting many files in minutes .
I need to keep on watching that folder and as soon as file arrives i have to upload into S3 .
The size of the files would be max 10 KB but frequency will be high .

Here is my code that watches the folder and start S3 upload .
But my issue is how can i pass file from file watch class to S3 uploader .

Here is my code to watch Folder

```
public class MonitorDirectory {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Path faxFolder = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\u6034690\\Desktop\\ONEFILE\\");
        WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        faxFolder.register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
        boolean valid = true;
        do {
            WatchKey watchKey = watchService.take();
            for (WatchEvent event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {
                WatchEvent.Kind kind = event.kind();
                if (StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(event.kind())) {
                    String fileName = event.context().toString();
                    UploadObject onj=new UploadObject();//How to pass file path here 
                    onj.uploadIntoS3();
                    System.out.println("File Created:" + fileName);
                }
            }
            valid = watchKey.reset();
        } while (valid);
    }
}
```

Here is my class where i upload file into S3 which works fine now

```
public class UploadObject {
    public  void uploadIntoS3() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String bucketName = "a205381-auditxml/S3UPLOADER";
        try {
            AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client();
            s3client.putObject(bucketName, "hello.txt",
                new File("C:\\Users\\u6034690\\Desktop\\ONEFILE\\hello.txt"));
            System.out.println("Uploaded onject");
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So how to pass file path from `MonitorDirectory` class to `onj.uploadIntoS3();`
Also one last check is my code going to sustain huge amount of file upload frequency .

Comment: Not clear to me why you cannot pass the file name as a parameter to `onj.uploadIntoS3(fileName)`

Comment: @petrch but that is name of the file ..We need to pass file path in order to upload path correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Get path like below inside for loop

```
final Path createdFile = (Path) event.context();
                final Path expectedAbsolutePath = watchedDirectory.resolve(createdFile);

                String fileName = event.context().toString();
                System.out.println("Full path: " + expectedAbsolutePath);
                UploadObject obj=new UploadObject();//How to pass file path here
```

and then pass in S3 uploader

```
obj.uploadIntoS3(expectedAbsolutePath.toFile());
```